# Invalid AWS Region: il-central-1 error while deploying EKS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy EKS Cluster using terraform.
Currently I am using source as "hashicorp/aws" and version: 5.16.0, I am trying to deploy in "il-central-1" region.

I am getting error as "Invalid AWS Region: il-central-1".

This is my provider block.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.16.0"
    }
    archive = {
      source = "hashicorp/archive"
    }
  }

    backend "s3" {
        bucket                 = "state-files"
        key                    = "terraform.tfstate"
        region                 = "il-central-1"
        dynamodb_table         = "terraform-lock"
        encrypt                = true
        skip_region_validation = true
    }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
```

This is my main.tf

```
# Define the EKS Cluster
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  version = var.cluster_version
  name     = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.role.arn
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxxx]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.eks_cluster_sg.id]
  }
  # kubernetes_network_config {
  #   service_ipv4_cidr = "xx.xx.xx.xx/22"
  # }
  
  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks_node_group" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  version         = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.version
  # release_version = nonsensitive(data.aws_ssm_parameter.eks_ami_release_version.value)  
  release_version = "xxxxxx"
  ami_type = "xxxxxx"
  # release_version = 
  disk_size = 20
  capacity_type = "ON_DEMAND"
  instance_types = ["xx.medium"]
  node_group_name = "xxxxxxxx"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodegroup_role.arn
  subnet_ids = [xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxx]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.desired_size
    max_size     = var.max_size
    min_size     = var.min_size
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }

resource "aws_eks_addon" "coredns" {
  cluster_name                = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.eks_node_group]
  addon_name                  = "coredns"
  addon_version               = "v1.10.1-eksbuild.4"
  service_account_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.eks_addon_role.arn
  resolve_conflicts_on_create = "OVERWRITE"

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "kube_proxy" {
  cluster_name        = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.eks_node_group]    
  addon_name        = "kube-proxy"
  addon_version     = "v1.27.4-eksbuild.2"
  resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
  service_account_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_addon_role.arn  
  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "vpc_cni" {
  cluster_name        = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.eks_node_group]  
  addon_name        = "vpc-cni"
  addon_version     = "xxxxxx"
  # resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
  service_account_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_addon_role.arn

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  cluster_name        = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.eks_node_group]
  addon_name          = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  addon_version       = "v1.22.0-eksbuild.2"
  resolve_conflicts   = "OVERWRITE"
  service_account_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_addon_role.arn
  tags = {
    Environment = "staging"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "efs_csi_driver" {
  cluster_name        = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  depends_on = [aws_eks_node_group.eks_node_group]
  addon_name          = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  addon_version       = "v1.5.8-eksbuild.1"
  resolve_conflicts   = "OVERWRITE"
  service_account_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_addon_role.arn
  tags = {
    Environment = "staging"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

data "tls_certificate" "eks_cluster_certificate" {
  url = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer
}
```

Full Error log:

```
Error: Invalid AWS Region: il-central-1
│
│   with module.eks.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on modules\eks\aws.tf line 14, in provider "aws":
│   14: provider "aws" {
│
```

I tried changing the version and tried to deploy in another region also, which returned same error, Now i am confuse from where it is taking the "il-central-1" region if i change the variable value to another region.

Is this because of bucket which is created in "il-central-1" region?

Comment: Did you define any `provider "aws"` blocks anywhere? Or are you using a default profile where that region is defined?

Comment: Yes I have mentioned the provider "aws" block and using the default profile and region is mentiond in tfvars file.

Comment: Would you mind adding that information to the question?

Comment: Wait, you cannot use variables in the `backend` block, i.e., `region  = var.aws_region` cannot work.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE Will updated the backend configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not due to the version or backend configuration; they were set up correctly, the backend was located in the il-central-1 region.

The issue was actually related to the remote.tf file. In the il-central-1 region, we were unable to access the tf.state file.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "XXXXXX"
    region = "il-central-1"
    key    = "XXXXXXX"
    skip_region_validation = true #Added the region validation and it works as charm.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but I don't see any way this particular solution could be connected to the error message you showed in your question. That error message was being returned from the `hashicorp/aws` provider rather than the "s3" backend. If the provider is now working then it's not super important, but I'm just noting it in case someone else finds this question and answer in future and might try to fix an AWS provider problem by changing an S3 backend configuration.

Comment: The forthcoming Terraform v1.6.0 release of Terraform CLI will also include a new version of the AWS SDK and supporting libraries, so I expect that it will support `il-central-1` without the need to "skip region validation".

Comment: Thank you @MartinAtkins, I will looking forward to see Terraform v1.6.0 Release

Answer (score 0):

Because AWS regions each have their own independent set of endpoints and other metadata, the `hashicorp/aws` provider has a table of supported regions built into it and each time AWS adds a new region it must be added to that table and included in a subsequent release of the provider.

[The `il-central-1` region was added to the relevant codebase on August 3 2023](https://github.com/hashicorp/aws-sdk-go-base/pull/586) and [was added to the `hashicorp/aws` provider in its v5.12.0 release](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v5.12.0/CHANGELOG.md), so you will need to use at least v5.12 of the `hashicorp/aws` provider for the region `il-central-1` to be accepted as valid.

The same would be true for any new AWS region added in the future: there will always be some minimum `hashicorp/aws` provider release that supports any given AWS region.

Comment: I think the question states version 5.16.0 is used.

Comment: Yes we are using 5.16.0 Version we tried with other version too.

Comment: In that case it would be helpful to edit the question to include the full error message _exactly as Terraform printed it_ (including any information about what part of the configuration it's referring to) and also the full output of `terraform version` to confirm what versions of Terraform CLI and providers are being used.

Comment: In particular I'm wondering if it's actually `backend "s3"` that's raising the error, rather than the provider. Having the full error message and knowing exactly which version of Terraform CLI you're using would help determine that.

Comment: I have added the full error log in question.